# Как узнать есть ли в листбоксе равные числа? Как это должно быть написано в цикле?

Tags: c#

Как узнать есть ли в листбоксе равные числа? Как это должно быть написано в цикле?

```
do { 
  a = v.Next(min, max + 1); 
  listBox1.Items.Add(a); 
  i++; 
  a = b; 
  a++; 
} while (i < n); 

if (a==a-a) { 
  s = "Одинаковые"; 
} else { 
  s = "Разные"; 
} 
label5.Text = s;
```

Comment: дайте, пожалуйста, определение "чисел в листбоксе"

Comment: в листбокс вводятся рандомные числа, мне надо поределить есть ли там числа, которые повторяются (например 11 повторилось три раза и тд)

Comment: "Главное заблуждение человечества - каждый думает, что говорит понятно."  Код покажите.

Comment: do
            {
                a = v.Next(min, max + 1);
                listBox1.Items.Add(a);
                i++;
                a = b;
                a++;
                
            }
            while (i < n);
            {
                if (a==a-a)
                {
                    s = "Одинаковые";
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    
                   s = "Разные"; 
                    
                }
                label5.Text = s;

Comment: a=b, a++ - неправильно, я не знаю как сравнивать эти числа в цикле

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
label6.Text
    = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Distinct().Count() == listBox1.Items.Count ?
    "разные" : "одинаковые";
```